# Trim string from string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I want to trim this string `/tmp/files/` from a variable `$FILES`
For example:

```
setenv FILES=/tmp/files/list
ONLY_L=`trim($FILES,'/tmp/files/')`
echo $ONLY_L
#should see only 'list'
```

I though of using `sed` for the job, but it look a little "ugly" because all the `\` that came before the `/`.

Comment: `setenv` is a `csh` command, not a `bash` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ONLY_L="${FILES##*/}"`

or

`ONLY_L="$(basename "$FILES")"`

or

`ONLY_L="$(echo "$FILES" | sed 's|.*/||')"`

does what you want

Answer (score 3):

For `sed`, you don't have to use `/`

For instance, this works as well:

```
echo $FILES | sed 's#/tmp/files/##'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the basename command for this. It automatically removes the path and leaves just the filename:

```
basename /tmp/files/list
```

Output:

```
list
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sed` or call tools. `bash` provides you this ability using `string substitution`.

```
$ FILES='/tmp/files/list'

# do this
$ echo "${FILES/\/tmp\/files\/}"
list

# or this
$ echo "${FILES##*/}"
list
```